# Concatenating a large number of vectors with similar variable names into a matrix in Octave

Tags: regex, wildcard, octave

I have a large number of vectors read into variables with similar looking names, for example, var1, var2, ... var3000. They all have same number of elements.

How can I concatenate them into a single matrix of size "number of variables X number of elements in individual variables"? I know vertcat and horzcat commands, but how to easily provide these 3000+ var* vectors into them as parameters? Is it possible to generate a comma separated list of these variables using the whos(pattern) command?

Yes, reading them into the same variable in the first place is an option, but just wanted to know the wildcard / regex options we might have in Octave to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`eval()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html).  But this is generally a [bad idea](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html).